# Is it possible for the user to change a model instance through the ajax request in Livewire?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

For security reasons, is it possible for the enduser to change the model in the livewire request?

For example, if I mount my component like this:

```
public $order;

public function mount(Order $order){
    $this->order = $order;
}
```

Can I be sure that this order instance won't be changed if the user tries to manipulate the request?

Comment: Rule of thumb, you can never trust anything that comes from the client (or any external source), so if `$order` comes from the front end, you can't trust it and need to validate it in the back end.

Comment: Yes, but I know livewire sends a checksum hash in every ajax request. So maybe the data is validated?

Comment: I don't know about this specific implementation, but if the value is set in the front end, then it can theoretically still be manipulated (since the checksum also would be made in the front end.) If the value originated from the back end to start with, and are just passed with some signed request (like JWT), then it can be trusted, but not if it's set in the front end.

Comment: If data is tampered with, Livewire's checksum won't match and you'll get an error. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/security